# How to solve a problem with InvalidAMIID.NotFound even if region are same, in main.TF and on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a problem with creating VM from Terraform on AWS.

I'm trying this:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "***"
  secret_key = "****"
  region = "us-east-1"
  profile = "default"
}

resource "aws_instance" "linux_test" {
  ami = "ami-0557a15b87f6559cf"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

My region is US-east-1 in code and on AWS console, also ami key is from east-1. Any idea?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well, for one, you don't need both the access keys and the profile name. Can you remove one of those and try again?

Comment: If I remove the access key message that I receive is that there are no valid credentials.

Comment: Have you saved the file? The ami shown in error message doesn't reflect your code

Comment: @PetarTomic Do you even have the `default` profile defined in the `~/.aws/credentials` file?

Comment: @Sathyajith Bhat, Marko E - Yes.


I communicated with AWS support, and they said there is a problem with account permissions, which will be solved ASAP. When they finish that task, I will inform you about the news. :)